# Problems with "start-process -wait" on Windows 10

Tags: powershell

**Update:**
Sorted the "issue" as soon as I posted the question. Apparently, Windows App or whatever they are called, the UWP "app" are executed differently, causing the issue. As soon as I not use the "calc" or any other Windows App, it runs as intended.

---

There is a list of programs I want to sequentially start and go through, and on each program's exit, the next program on the list (array) would start.

The code works on Windows 7 SP1, even with PowerShell version 5 (though I know it's not exactly the same)

However, when I run it on Windows 10 Creative Update (I don't have another version on hand) it went wrong, the `-Wait` parameter does not appear to function.

I am open to alternative Powershell cmdlets too, if it has a reasonably simple "Wait" function.

```
# Common variable
$programlist = "calc", "notepad", "excel", "winword", "powerpnt"

-----
# Example 1
ForEach ($program in $programlist) {(Start-Process $program -Wait).WaitForExit;}

# Example 2
ForEach ($program in $programlist) {Start-Process $program -Wait -Passthru;}

# Example 3
Start-Process $programlist[0] -Wait
Start-Process $programlist[1] -Wait
...

# None of the examples work in Win 10, but works perfectly fine on Win7
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>I can't repeat your issue on my Win10, PS version 5.0.</del>

<del>Your code works very well.</del>

<del>Can you provide more details?</del>

Good to hear it~

Comment: Check the top section where I put the "update", the problem with my code was the "calc", the "calc" app in Win10 is a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) program, it doesn't follow the traditional x86 "-Wait" command in the code.